# Asynchronously control the BusyIndicator

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Apparently all Eclipse/SWT has in the way of managing the busy mouse indicator is

```
BusyIndicator.showWhile(Runnable synchronousStuffToDo)
```

However, I have a fundamentally event-oriented project where "stuff to do" doesn't happen within a sequential line of execution: an action gets ordered and a continuation-callback is provided to the execution manager. Therefore I have nothing meaningful to put into that `synchronousStuffToDo` runnable.

Is there another, however low-level and clumsy, but *platform-independent* way of manipulating the busy indicator asynchronously, which means two separate method calls, "activate it" and "deactivate it"?

I should add `ProgressMonitorDialog` to this question because it appears to suffer from the same problem. Yes, within the `ProgressMonitorDialog#run` method an inner event loop will be spinned, but SWT event loop is just one of my execution managers, so the chain will still be broken. Apparently without this class I can't even show a progress monitor except if I reimplement from lower-level primitives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way you can manipulate the `Cursor` using the `BusyIndicator` class.
You can invoke the below util method to show a Busy Icon while running your job on a background `Thread`

```
public static void imBusy(final boolean busy){

    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Shell shell = Display.getDefault().getActiveShell();
            if(busy){ //show Busy Cursor
                Cursor cursor = Display.getDefault().getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_WAIT);          
                shell.setCursor(cursor);
            }else{  
                shell.setCursor(null);
            }   
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks; in the meantime I copied code from the Busyindicator class. It amounts to a similar thing but sets the cursor on all shells.

Answer (score 0):

Your runnable should wait for the task completion. E.g. (code written in browser, will not compile - I'm ignoring exceptions):

```
final Object condition = new Object();
BusyIndicator.showWhile(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(condition) {
            while (!isMyTaskDoneFlag()) {
                condition.wait();
            }
        }
    }
});
doTask(new MyTask() {
    public void perform() {
        try {
            // Task logic
            ...
        } finally {
            // When done
            setMyTaskDoneFlag();
            synchronized(condition) {
                condition.notify();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Make sure all code paths in your tasks do not forget to unblock the runnable. Pretty much the same approach can be used with progress monitors - you may wake your runnable to update progress monitor value.

Note: You need to make sure the waiting runnable is not executed on SWT thread (e.g. set `fork` to `true` if running in progress monitor) or else your application will become unresponsive.

Comment: This is just the kind of stuff I'm trying hard to avoid :-) It wastes a thread to do nothing but wait, and doesn't give anything in return.

Comment: I never use BusyIndicator (prefer infinite progress monitors if I have to lock the UI for unknown duration - this way user has better understanding somethings is actually going on) and this is the most reliable way. I don't think for UI application (e.g. inherently single-user) extra thread that is waiting on condition is really consuming considerable resources.

Comment: I'm still experimenting, might go just with the progress dialog. As for the blocked thread, I reject it on general principle. In the meantime I  have shaped the ProgressMonitorDialog code to have the same feature, only asynchronously.

Comment: I thought I was the only one who suffered this problem, I had a simple solution for my needs, though not elegant. This may be helpful. http://pastebin.com/hZpXCrWe

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (which I don't particularly like, but it works) in an older SWT application I'm working on now. It uses `BusyIndicator#showWhile`, and the synchronous stuff it does inside is:

1. Start the asynch task in a background thread
2. Loop waiting for the background thread to finish up while at the same time spinning the
   SWT event loop explicitly:

```java
while (!taskDone){
    if (!display.readAndDispatch() && !shell.isDisposed()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
    taskDone = //check for task progress
    //update something on the main window status bar
}
```

I'm trying to convert this to something cleaner (along the lines of what Marko suggested):

1. Set the busy icon
2. Submit background task
3. Unset the busy icon

but I'm not sure what would be best for updating the status bar (background tasks are actually remote calls so their thread is blocked until they finish up). I'm thinking of having a dedicated thread that detects when background jobs are running and update the status bar accordingly (the update is just an unfolding dotted line, nothing task specific), but using a thread just for this seems a bit of a waste.

Comment: I just realized that this technique has a very nasty problem: if a task t1 is started, then a second one, t2 is also started before t1 finishes, t1 completion cannot be detected until t2 also finishes because t1's status check is suspended by the inner check loop started for t2